# Drawing shapes on image and saving it in PHP

Tags: php, html

I am trying to read an image from a location in my server and then draw lines on it and then overwrite the image in the location.

My code is as follows:

```
function drawShapes($src_path, $json)
{       
    echo "---inside draw Sharpes-------";
    $x1= $json['x1'];
    $y1= $json['y1'];
    $x2= $json['x2'];
    $y2= $json['y2'];
    $x3= $json['x3'];
    $y3= $json['y3'];
    $x4= $json['x4'];
    $y4= $json['y4'];

    $type = exif_imagetype($src_path);
    $allowedTypes = array( 
        1,  // [] gif 
        2,  // [] jpg 
        3,  // [] png 
    ); 
    if (!in_array($type, $allowedTypes)) { 
        return false; 
    } 
    switch ($type) { 
        case 1 : 
            $im = imageCreateFromGif($src_path); 
        break; 
        case 2 :    
            $im = imageCreateFromJpeg($src_path);               
        break; 
        case 3 : 
            $im = imageCreateFromPng($src_path); 
        break; 
    }  

    if (!$im)
        return false;

    imagesetthickness($im, 5);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    echo $color;

    imageline($im, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $color);
    imageline($im, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, $color);
    imageline($im, $x3, $y3, $x4, $y4, $color);
    imageline($im, $x4, $y4, $x1, $y1, $color);

    header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
    imagejpeg($im,$src_path);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Here $src_path= "uploads/case.jpg"- uploads is a folder inside my solution & case.jpg is the image file name.
But I am getting image missing icon as output. What is the mistake I do?

What is the solution to it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are echoing data before you send the headers.

If you want to overwrite the image in the location and then display it in the browser, maybe you can work with this adjustment:

```
<?php
function drawShapes($src_path, $json)
{
    //echo "---inside draw Sharpes-------";
    $x1= $json['x1'];
    $y1= $json['y1'];
    $x2= $json['x2'];
    $y2= $json['y2'];
    $x3= $json['x3'];
    $y3= $json['y3'];
    $x4= $json['x4'];
    $y4= $json['y4'];

    $type = exif_imagetype($src_path);
    $allowedTypes = array(
        1,  // [] gif
        2,  // [] jpg
        3,  // [] png
    );
    if (!in_array($type, $allowedTypes)) {
        return false;
    }
    switch ($type) {
        case 1 :
            $im = imageCreateFromGif($src_path);
            break;
        case 2 :
            $im = imageCreateFromJpeg($src_path);
            break;
        case 3 :
            $im = imageCreateFromPng($src_path);
            break;
    }

    if (!$im)
        return false;

    imagesetthickness($im, 5);
    $color = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    //echo $color;

    imageline($im, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $color);
    imageline($im, $x2, $y2, $x3, $y3, $color);
    imageline($im, $x3, $y3, $x4, $y4, $color);
    imageline($im, $x4, $y4, $x1, $y1, $color);

    imagejpeg($im,$src_path);
    imagedestroy($im);

    $fp = fopen($src_path, 'rb');
    header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
    header("Content-Length: " . filesize($src_path));
    fpassthru($fp);
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It worked. I want to redirect to another php file, which should display the new image in a img tag. So I used the code,  session_start();
$_SESSION['url'] = $url_path;
header("Location: Result.php"); - I pasted this code after 'exit;'- but I am getting image missing icon as output. It works independently before.

Comment: It gives the warning: Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: Add this code to your Result.php: `session_start();$src_path = $_SESSION['url'];$fp = fopen($src_path, 'rb');header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");header("Content-Length: " . filesize($src_path));fpassthru($fp);exit;`

Then replace this code in your function drawShapes:
`$fp = fopen($src_path, 'rb'); header("Content-Type: image/jpeg"); header("Content-Length: " . filesize($src_path)); fpassthru($fp); exit;`

With this:
`session_start(); $_SESSION['url'] = $src_path; header("Location: Result.php");`

Comment: Thank :) I used your suggestion, and it was still giving a broken image. Then I commented out the 2 headers and fpassthru(), and it worked. I do not know how though.